# Do i have to list all controller functions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Do i have to list all controller functions in `Global.asax.cs` file?

Im creating a api for my workout and have created the controller WorkoutController. It has the action AddWorkout that takes some parameters, for instance username, password, duration and type. Two first are string, two last is ints.

Now, do i need to create a route for it? And every action with different action signature? Why could it not fall in under the default route? Calling it would break if i dont supply the correct variables, but i know what im doing :D

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "AddWorkout", // Route name
                "Workout/AddWorkout/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Workout", action = "AddWorkout" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

??? :D ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a **[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)** Api:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Workout", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and use for example of your **Workout**:

```
public class WorkoutController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Help");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Workout(FormCollection form)
    {
        // HTTP POST: ADD Workout

        // process form and return JSON
        return Json(myObject);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Workout(string id)
    {
        // HTTP DELETE: REMOVE Workout

        // process form and return JSON
        return Json(myObject);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Workout(string id)
    {
        // HTTP GET: GET Workout

        // process form and return JSON
        return Json(myObject);
    }
}
```

But I would suggest you to use WCF though :)

From a client side:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Workout/Workout",
   data: { 
           'type': '123456', 
           'height': '171'
         }
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });


$.ajax({
   type: "DELETE",
   url: "/Workout/Workout",
   data: { 'id': '123456' }
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });


$.get("/Workout/Workout", { 'id': '123456' }, function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
```

remember to create a **Login** method that you would send a `token` that is required in all actions, so you know that the user manipulating your data is `real`.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx).

> The "Url" property on the Route class defines the Url matching rule
>   that should be used to evaluate if a route rule applies to a
>   particular incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to do this at all. The default route looks at what methods are defined and will figure out what to call as long as your parameters line up to some method on the controller.